# hacer que un condicional solo afecta a un numero determinado de elementos con mismo atributo

Tags: javascript

```js
class Edificio {

 constructor(celda_id, nombre){

  this._celda = celda_id;
  this._nombre = nombre;
 }

 get tipo(){
  return this._tipo;
 }

 trazar(){

  const celdas = opener.document.getElementsByClassName('celda');

  for (let elm of celdas) {

   if (elm.dataset.celda === this._celda) {

    elm.dataset.edificio = this._nombre;
   }
  }
 }
}

class Atraccion extends Edificio {

 constructor(celda_id, nombre, visitantes){

  super(celda_id, nombre);
  this._visitantes = visitantes;
  this._tipo = "atraccion";
 }

 get visitantes(){
  return parseInt(this._visitantes);
 }
}

class Puesto extends Edificio {

 constructor(celda_id, nombre, ingresos){

  super(celda_id, nombre);
  this._ingresos = ingresos;
  this._tipo = "puesto";
 }

 get ingresos(){
  return parseInt(this._ingresos);
 }
}



const edificios = document.getElementsByClassName('edificio');

for (let elm of edificios) {

 elm.onclick = function(){

  if (elm.dataset.coste <= opener.objPartida.saldo) {

   const tipo = elm.dataset.tipo;
   const nombre = elm.dataset.nombre;
   const celda = opener.numeroCelda;

   if (tipo === "atraccion") {

    const visitantes = elm.dataset.visitantes;

    const atraccion = new Atraccion(celda, nombre, visitantes);
    atraccion.trazar();

    opener.objPartida.parque.push(atraccion);
   }

   if (tipo === "puesto") {

    const ingresos = elm.dataset.ingresos;

    const puesto = new Puesto(celda, nombre, ingresos);
    puesto.trazar();

    opener.objPartida.parque.push(puesto);
   }

   opener.objPartida.saldo -= elm.dataset.coste;

   opener.msg("success", "Edificio creado");

   window.close();
  
  } else {

   msg('error', 'Saldo insuficiente (' + opener.objPartida.saldo + '$ restantes)');
  }
 }
}
```

Quisiera hacer que este condicional solo afecte a dos elementos para cambiar su atributo **`data-edificio = vacia`** siendo su anterior valor otro. No sé cómo poner el condicional. Quiero cambiar, por ejemplo sólo **`data-edificio = "noria"`** y **`data-edificio = "troncos"`** a **`data-edificio = "vacia"`**.

```
 for (let elm of celdas) {

    if() //este condicional no sé cómo ponerlo
       elm.dataset.edificio = "vacia";
 }
```

Gracias.

Un saludo,

```html
   

 <div class="mapa">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="01"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="troncos" data-celda="02"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="noria" data-celda="03"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="auditorio" data-celda="04"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="05"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="06"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="07"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="08"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="09"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="10"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="11"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="12"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas, con qué método puedes obtener el valor de data-edificio? Es este: `elm.dataset.edificio` ?

Comment: Y, otra pregunta, lo que quieres es que todos los elementos que no tengan un valor "vacía" pasen a ser "vacía"?

Comment: HOla JCAguilera, gracias por tu respuesta. Se ha creado mediante una clase, un metodo trazar() que cambia el data-edificio por el nombre de la atraccion.He añadido el código para que lo veas. Es lo que quiero revertir, pero sólo para dos de los doce elementos posibles que han podido ser cambiados (cada vez que selcciono una celda, y por ende un edificio a construir, se cambia vacia por el nombre de edificio). si le pongo for(elm of celdas) if (elm.dataset.edificio = nombre) {elm.dataset.edificio="vacia"} no me funciona.

Comment: porque no trazar pasas por parametro la celda?

Answer (score 1):

No me quedó muy claro cual es tu objetivo final, pero el condicional es sencillo. Esto sirve para los valores en concreto ('noria','troncos')

```
for (let elm of celdas) {
if(elm.dataset.edificio == "noria" || elm.dataset.edificio == "troncos" ){ //este condicional no sé cómo ponerlo
   elm.dataset.edificio = "vacia";
}
```

Otra alternativa seria cambiar todos los valores que sean diferentes al valor que deseas modificar ('vacia').

```
for (let elm of celdas) {
if(elm.dataset.edificio != "vacia"){ //este condicional no sé cómo ponerlo
   elm.dataset.edificio = "vacia";
}
```

Comment: El tema es que mediante un metodo constructor, una clase, se le cambia el data-edificio = "vacia" por le data-nombre="nombre-de-la-atraccion" de un conjunto de doce atracciones y restaurantes diferentes.  class Edificio {

 constructor(celda_id, nombre){

  this._celda = celda_id;
  this._nombre = nombre;
 }

 get tipo(){
  return this._tipo;
 }

 trazar(){

  const celdas = opener.document.getElementsByClassName('celda');

  for (let elm of celdas) {

   if (elm.dataset.celda === this._celda) {

    elm.dataset.edificio = this._nombre; //aquí
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: Gracias Victor!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) de esta forma puedes seleccionar elementos por sus atributos. Tu código quedaría así:

```js
function cambiar(){
$("[data-edificio='noria']").attr("data-edificio","vacia");
$("[data-edificio='troncos']").attr("data-edificio","vacia");
checkValue()

}
function checkValue(){
console.log("Data celda 03 anteriormente noria: "+$("[data-celda='03']").attr("data-edificio"));
console.log("Data celda 03 anteriormente troncos: "+$("[data-celda='02']").attr("data-edificio"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mapa">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="01"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="troncos" data-celda="02"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="noria" data-celda="03"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="auditorio" data-celda="04"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="05"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="06"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="07"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="08"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="09"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="10"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="11"></div>
   <div class="celda" data-edificio="vacia" data-celda="12"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
    <button onclick="cambiar()">Cambiar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias Fran!!!

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo tu pregunta entendí (mas o menos) que querías que los elementos con `data-edificio = "noria"` y `data-edificio = "troncos"` se cambiasen a `data-edificio = "vacía"`. En ese caso, este es el condicional que debieses usar:

```
for (let elm of celdas) {
    if(elm.dataset.edificio === 'noria' || data-edificio === 'troncos') {
        elm.dataset.edificio = "vacia";
    }
}
```

Aquí decimos: "SI elm.dataset.edificio ES IGUAL A 'noria' O elm.dataset.edificio ES IGUAL A 'troncos', entonces cambia elm.dataset.edificio a 'vacía'".

Ahora si quieres que cualquier elemento que NO tenga `data-edificio = "vacía"` cambie a `data-edificio = "vacía"`, este sería el condicional a utilizar:

```
for (let elm of celdas) {
    if(elm.dataset.edificio !== 'vacía') {
        elm.dataset.edificio = "vacia";
    }
}
```

Espero que esto resuelva tu pregunta.